# How to create a a nested xml structure with two elements?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to create a xml structure like :

```
<OuterMostElement>
  <NestedSet>
      <Element></Element>
      <Element></Element>
  </NestedSet>
</OuterMostElement>
```

I am calling a method `createNestedSet` two times succesively to create this structure passing it the `<OuterMostElement>` document fragment.

```
   <OuterMostElement>
      <NestedSet>
          <Element></Element>
      </NestedSet>
      <NestedSet>
          <Element></Element>
      </NestedSet>
    </OuterMostElement>
```

The method is :

```
  public static void createNestedSet(DocumentFragment df) {
        if (oTargetLineProperties.isRendered()) {
            Document doc = df.getOwnerDocument();
            Element newParentElem = null;
            newParentElem = createTagIfAbsent(doc, "somenamespace", "NestedSet");
            Element newElem = null;
            newElem = doc.createElementNS("someNameSpace",
                                        "Element");

            newParentElem.appendChild(newElem);
            ((XMLElement)df.getFirstChild()).appendChild(newParentElem);
        }
    }
```

And the helper method  `createTagIfAbsent` is the following :

```
  private static Element createTagIfAbsent(Document doc, String nameSpace, String tagName) {
        Element newParentElem;
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        //Already contains tag . So just return the existing one
        if(nodes!=null && nodes.getLength() > 0){
            newParentElem = (Element)nodes.item(0) ;
        }else{
            newParentElem = doc.createElementNS(nameSpace,tagName);  
        }

        return newParentElem;
    }
```

Why the idea of creating the `NestedSet` tag only if it is absent not working correctly ?

Comment: does not directly answer your question but why not create a better API: `createNestedSet( Document doc, List<_NestedSet_> set )`

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, you need to use getElementsByTagNameNS

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagNameNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

To get the Element you want to get, passing the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use [xStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to marshal an instance of this class:

```
public class OuterMostElement {
   private final Set<Element> nestedSet = new HashSet<Element>();

   public void add(Element element) {
     nestedSet.add(element);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     XStream xstream = new XStream();

     OuterMostElement ome = new OuterMostElement();
     ome.add(new Element(1));
     ome.add(new Element(2));

     String result = xstream.toXml(ome);
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: @Bors can you see what I did wrong ?I have simplified these methods to give simplified example . using XStream is not an option here .

Comment: @Geek I mention what you did wrong, you don't provide the namespace in the getElementsByTagName, so in xml this is not the same kind of element.